# Proving a single-term function is big Omega

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I was given the function 5n^3+2n+8 to prove for big-O and big-Omega. I finished big-O, but for big-Omega I end up with a single-term function. I canceled out 2n and 8 because they're positive and make my function larger, so I just end up with 5n^3. How do I choose C and n_0? or is it simply trivial in this case?

Answer (score 0):

From [Big-Ω (Big-Omega) notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-omega-notation) (slightly modified):

> If a running time of some function `f(n)` is `Ω(g(n))`, then for large
>   enough `n`, say `n > n_0 > 0`, the running time of `f(n)` is at least
>   `C⋅g(n)`, for some constant `C > 0`.

Hence, if `f(n)` is in `Ω(g(n))`, then there exists some positive constants `C` and `n_0` such at the following holds

```
f(n) ≥ C⋅g(n), for all n > n_0                                 (+)
```

Now, the choice of `C` and `n_0` is not unique, it suffices that you can show one such set of constants (such that `(+)` holds) to be able to describe the running time using the Big-Omega notation, as posted above.

Hence, you are indeed almost there

```
f(n) = 5n^3+2n+8 > 5n^3 holds for all n larger than say, 1

    => f(n) ≥ 5⋅n^3 for all n > n_0 = 1                         (++)
```

Finally, `(++)` is just `(+)` for `g(n) = n^3` and `C=5`, and hence, by `(+)`, `f(n)` is in `Ω(n^3)`.